# JavaScript Code needed to rename file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm trying to remove characters after numbers and needs to include .pdf extension.

I cannot use index since the file name varies on dates and names.

Ex: My File Name : Mar 1316 and A - sec.pdf

Required Output File Name: Mar1316.pdf

can anyone help with the simple JavaScript to achieve above result? I tried using replace and split method unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
var org = "Mar 1316 and A - sec.pdf";
org = org.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/(?<=\d{4}).*(?=\.)/g, '');
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

You can accomplish this using regular expressions. The positive lookbehind (?<=) and lookahead (?=) expressions allow you to focus on all characters in between them. A period represents a single character and the asterisk is a modifier to search for zero or more occurences. So .* is looking at zero or more characters that are preceded by 4 digits, or \d{4}, and proceeded by a period. The first replace was used to remove all spaces beforehand, for the sake of simplicity. The g you see after the second forward slashes is a global modifier, which will replace all occurences instead of just the first.

Sidenote: The lookahead for a period needs to be escaped, using a backslash character since it's a special character.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to use above logic in my code throws syntax error?      String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
var str = name;

str = str.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/(?<=\d{4}).*(?=\.)/g, '');

newName = str;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1jrkxy8o/
Try playing around in this to see if you can figure out what isn't working. Without more context and the specific error message, it's hard to say exactly what went wrong.